# How to override inherited svg style

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am making a visualization program with d3 javascript.

There is a big group of lines. all the lines should start with opacity of 0.1. In this big group, there are some small groups. When an event is triggered, one of small groups visible and all other small groups invisible. Which small group is visible is dependent on the trigger event. I want to make one of small groups visible and all other small groups invisible by setting the opacity attribute.

So is there any keyword to make the group override the attribute or the style from its parent? Or is there any other similar attribute or style which can be overridden? Otherwise I may have to use for loop to traverse and modify every small groups, which is not very efficient.

```
<svg width="1000" height="500">
<g class="big_group" style="opacity: 0;">
    <g class='small_group inherit_opacity'>
        <line x1="100" y1="100" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke: black;"></line>
    </g>
    <g class='small_group inherit_opacity'>
        <line x1="200" y1="100" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke: black;"></line>
    </g>
    
    <g class='small_group' id='try_to_override_opacity_but_fail' style="opacity: 1;">
        <line x1="300" y1="200" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke: black;"></line>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

I intuitively thought there might be some kind of "override" keyword in "try_to_override_opacity_but_fail" to override the opacity in parent group.

Comment: Please show that you've searched for a solution, preferably by finding ones that don't work and telling us why they don't.

Comment: The problem is that opacities _multiply_. So that 0 * 1 is still 0. If you could reverse the logic so that the top group has opacity of 1, and the elements that need to be hidden are 0, then it would work.

Comment: Why don't you use the visibility property rather than the opacity property?

Answer (score 0):

Only if you define the initial opacity with CSS, not with a `style` attribute:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 500">
  <style>
    g{
      opacity:0;
      stroke:black;
      stroke-width:10;
    }
  </style>
  <g>
    <line x1="100" y1="100" x2="200" y2="200"></line>
  </g>
  <g>
    <line x1="200" y1="100" x2="200" y2="200"></line>
  </g>
  <g style="opacity:1;">
    <line x1="300" y1="200" x2="200" y2="200"></line>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

the .svg files works fine with css
so you can style them like:

```
svg {
    width: 200px;
    & > g {
        path:nth-last-of-type(2) {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

if you need to made changes dynamically, should read about style the elements by javascript ;)